# Calling setTimeout jquery function multiple times

Tags: jquery, settimeout, fadeout

I have this function:

```
<script>
var loop_handle;
var xSeconds = 10000; // 1 second

loop_handle = setInterval(function() {
$('#overlay').fadeOut('fast');
$('#box').hide();
}, xSeconds);
</script>
```

I wanted to display and fadeout an array of:

```
<div id="overlay">text</div>
```

But it seems it only works once. How can I make it work for all the arrays or call it multiple times?

Comment: Which array? BTW `10000 ms = 10s` and ids should be unique. If you want to have multiple elements with a common identifier use classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
var xSeconds = 10000; // 1 second
```

Should be:

```
var xSeconds = 1000; // 1 second
```

Comment: or `var xSeconds = 10000; // 10 seconds` :)

Comment: Sirko mentioned earlier, "which array?" I just assumed what adam meant was that his interval never seemed to loop... which would be caused potentially, by failing to wait every 10 seconds for it (because you thought it would happen every second)

Comment: @ShazboticusSShazbot I think there's a more serious problem with OP's idea

Comment: @JanDvorak Yeah... either that or he's trying to fade out the overlay every 10 seconds. In which case... he'd have to unhide it before each fade.

Comment: yes that is 10 sec, what I want is at the the start of a youtube video, there is an overlay of caption then disappears after 10sec.. but it only triggers once, after it, if i play the other videos, the #overlay doesnt work anymore.. do i have to nest it? i mean the function?

Comment: @AdamIbrahimAlimCanape When you play the other videos, you have to unhide the #overlay, because you've faded it out. $('#overlay').show();
$('#box').show(); //not sure if you need this